# Version control my python projects resource files

Tags: python, svn, version-control, pycharm

I'm currently moving a project between home and work using svn. The IDE I'm using is PyCharm which I find awsome. I get everything integrated into one tool.

PyCharm has the ability to create a setup.py from the virtualenv for me that I also commit to svn.

By default PyCharm is adding files to my svn repo with full recursion.

Should I also let PyCharm add the `Include` and `Lib` folders of my project and the `Scripts` folder? I run version 2.6 at work and 2.7 at home but I don't really want that to matter either since code wise it doesn't.

To me it seems better if that is updated on the other machine running `python setup.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Include`, `Lib` and `Scripts` folders being part of virtualenv are not part of your project thus they should not be under vcs control. You might find [PyCharm: versioning .idea folder while keeping different interpreters across developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983545/) interesting as well. In addition you might want to take a look at pip requirements file as a mean to recreate the same environment for your project on different computers.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I wanted to hear :)