# cross platform *.IML files

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I've a project which I develop both in Windows and Linux.
The IML file is a problem for me because the location of the Python interpreter.
It is stored in the

```
<orderEntry type="jdk" jdkType="Python SDK" jdkName="...">
```

- On Windows, it points to: C:\Python27\python.exe
- On Linux, it points to: /usr/bin/python2.7

How can I square this circle? Can I simply not check-in the IML file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I easily share a PyCharm project across multiple operating systems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440025/can-i-easily-share-a-pycharm-project-across-multiple-operating-systems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpreters paths are stored globally, in PyCharm preferences. But the Python interpreter selected for the project is stored in project by name. The full interpreter path is used as interpreter name by default (that is obviously different on different platforms). If you need to share your project files, you need to specify a different name for your interpreter. This can be done in "File | Settings | Project Interpreter | Interpreter Settings (Gear Icon) | More... | Edit"

See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-13390#comment=27-759239