# How do I setup the python interpreter in pycharm for a cross-platform project?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a cross-platform python project (it's a whole bunch of scripts) that I run (and develop) on Windows as well as Linux (Redhat and Ubuntu). Everything works fine except the fact that I have to go and "Configure Python Interpreter" everytime I open the project in a different operating system.

My python executable locations for the Windows and Linux systems are something like:
For windows: c:/Anaconda/python.exe
For linux: /home/username/anaconda/python

Is there a way that I can make Pycharm point to the right Python Interpreter based on the Operating system that is opened in ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I jumped the gun on this one...some one has already answered this question here: [Share a PyCharm project across multiple operating systems (different interpreter paths)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440025/share-a-pycharm-project-across-multiple-operating-systems-different-interpreter)